# Issues with dimensions when using UIKit with SpriteKit

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uikit, 2d-games

I have a problem using UIKit with my SpriteKit game in landscape mode. I'm trying to create a menu system using UIKit.

I notice that when I switch from one viewcontroller to another that `viewWillLayoutSubviews` is called multiple times.  This problem is solved by using viewDidLoad instead.. but then the dimensions for my landscape game aren't correct.  Here's some of my code

```
func application(application: UIApplication!, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary!) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    let menuController = MenuController()

    let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: menuController)
    navController.navigationBarHidden = true

    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    self.window!.rootViewController = navController
    return true
}
```

I go to game using this action

```
func goToGame(sender: UIButton!){
    let gameController = GameViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    self.navigationController.pushViewController(gameController, animated: false)
}
```

It's at this point `viewWillLayoutSubviews` in my GameController is being called multiple times. This doesn't happen if I don't use my `UINavigationController` code in appdelegate

How can I keep my game landscape while keeping my menu system?

Comment: actually this is happening in general everytime i move to any viewcontroller..

Comment: i used "viewDidAppear" instead..  anything wrong with that?